# Locking MNC in Quectel EC25 modem

Tags: gsm, at-command, qualcomm, umts, quectel

I have a Quectel EC25 modem and I do not plug the SIM card.
When I want to set a different technology (2G, 3G, 4G) or different operator (MNC) using the following commands, "servingcell" is still the previous one.

```
AT+QENG="servingcell"

+QENG: "servingcell","LIMSRV","WCDMA",432,35,5962,9C58AFF,2993,453,1,-57,-11,-,-,-,-,-

OK
AT+COPS=1,2,"43235",0

OK
AT+QENG="servingcell"

+QENG: "servingcell","LIMSRV","WCDMA",432,35,5962,9C58AFF,2993,453,1,-57,-5,-,-,-,-,-

OK
AT+COPS=1,2,"43211",2

OK
AT+QENG="servingcell"

+QENG: "servingcell","LIMSRV","WCDMA",432,35,5962,9C58AFF,2993,453,1,-60,-6,-,-,-,-,-

OK
```

How can I apply the above locking on the modem? Is there a memory or similar concept which the current serving cell information is stored and I have to reset or clear before/after locking on the MNC or technology? Is there a complementary command to satisfy the locking conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an EC25 to try myself, but I'm going to provide an answer based on my standard AT commands knowledge.

**In abstract, I'm suggesting you to use `+COPS` only.**

In fact, looking to [Quectel EC25 AT commands guide](https://itbrainpower.net/downloadables/Quectel_EC25_EC21_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.0.pdf), `+QENG` command description is missing. Googling it I found out that it is a command for enabling enginering mode, and it syntax seems to vary.

---

**Strategy:**

1. Verify the list of supported operators by issuing `AT+COPS=?`

Its response is provided in the format

```
+COPS: [list of supported (<stat> ,<oper (in <format>=0)>,,<oper (in <format>=2)>,< AcT>)s][,,(list of supported <mode>s),(list of supported<format>s)]
```

In which you will see the list currently *seen* by the device.

Please note that, for every operator, **stat** can have following values:

```
0 Unknown
1 Operator available
2 Current operator
3 Operator forbidden
```

This will be useful later.

---

2. Force the manual selection of the operator. It is what you already do:

```
AT+COPS=1,2,"43211",2
```

which, according to command description in the guide linked above, means *"Force manual operator selection, in numeric format, to operator "43211", with UTRAN technology"*

Please note that

- `OK` might be returned even if the desired network is currently unavailable
- Some time is required after the `OK` for the actuar registration to the new operator. So, **make sure to wait enough time before querying  the current status**. In the meantime you can also query registration status by issuing `AT+CREG?`

---

3. After waiting enough time after `+COPS` set command, query new status. You can either

   - Issue read command `AT+COPS?`, that will provide the information about the current operator
   - Issue test command again, `AT+COPS=?`, in which the *stat* parameter for current operator is 2. If it is true for the operator we just forced, everything is ok.